# What is a French equivalent for the office slang phrase "knife and fork it (the problem)"?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, argot

Please, help me to find an appropriate equivalent!

Edit: To "knife and fork" a problem, in the English language, means to "give it a try," perhaps without expecting good results, or with low expectations. Source: [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/money/2013/oct/22/a-z-modern-office-jargon)

Comment: It would be helpful to explain what "kinfe and fork" means in office slang.

Comment: One of many food-related phrases that have polluted the office lexicon in the past 10 years, to ” knife-and-fork” a problem means to deal with it bit by bit. “We’ll have to knife and fork it,” a beleaguered manager might cry.  If you’ve been urged to “eat your own dogfood” (sample your own products) or “eat some reality sandwich” (be realistic), you might probably prefer a new job.

Comment: got it, and I have a possible answer in mind. I strongly advise you to edit your question and add that definition, I expect it will call for more answers.

Comment: Hi and welcome to French Language SE! Could you please add the clarification from your comment to the question itself? The question itself currently looks to much like a translation request without context and is therefore at risk of being closed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep a food-related word, the verb *saucissonner* may be adequate. Literally, it means "to divide in slices, like a sausage", but is frequently used in French office slang.

It sometimes has a negative connotation, as it can imply that the "slicing" was done for questionable reasons, or with no transparency, or just for the sake of splitting responsibilities, etc.

> Le management a décidé de saucissonner le projet, et il y a maintenant 5 chefs de projet et 5 équipes qui travaillent dessus.

Answer (score 0):

Not equivalent as far as being slang is concerned but otherwise, an expression used to positively describe this kind of approach to solve a problem (deal with it bit by bit) is:

- *Procéder par étapes*

Answer (score 0):

Si l'on veut conserver une expression imagée, je dirais

- Avancer pas à pas
- Avancer (poser) un pied après l'autre